# Multiple conflicting drivers for reg assigned in only one always block

Tags: verilog, yosys

I'm working on a simple video signal timing module in Verilog, as a learning project. I've understood from earlier study that each `reg` should be assigned from only one `always` block, so I arranged my system into two state machine blocks and then one block for populating the output registers, as shown below:

```
module video_timing
(
    input wire reset,
    input wire clk,

    output reg [15:0] x,
    output reg [15:0] y,
    output reg hsync,
    output reg vsync,
    output reg visible
);

    // State constants for our two timing state machines (one horizontal, one vertical)
    `define VIDEO_SYNC       2'd0
    `define VIDEO_BACKPORCH  2'd1
    `define VIDEO_ACTIVE     2'd2
    `define VIDEO_FRONTPORCH 2'd3

    // These settings are for 720p, assuming clk is running at 74.25 MHz
    `define VIDEO_H_SYNC_PIXELS   16'd40
    `define VIDEO_H_BP_PIXELS     16'd220
    `define VIDEO_H_ACTIVE_PIXELS 16'd1280
    `define VIDEO_H_FP_PIXELS     16'd110
    `define VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE   1'b1
    `define VIDEO_V_SYNC_LINES    16'd5
    `define VIDEO_V_BP_LINES      16'd20
    `define VIDEO_V_ACTIVE_LINES  16'd720
    `define VIDEO_V_FP_LINES      16'd5
    `define VIDEO_V_SYNC_ACTIVE   1'b1

    reg [1:0] state_h;
    reg [15:0] count_h; // 1-based so we will stop when count_h is the total pixels for the current state
    reg inc_v = 1'b0;
    reg [1:0] state_v;
    reg [15:0] count_v; // 1-based so we will stop when count_v is the total lines for the current state

    // Change outputs on clock.
    // (These update one clock step behind everything else below, but that's
    //  okay because the lengths of all the periods are still correct.)
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            hsync   <= ~`VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE;
            vsync   <= ~`VIDEO_V_SYNC_ACTIVE;
            visible <= 1'b0;
            x       <= 16'd0;
            y       <= 16'd0;
        end else begin
            hsync   <= (state_h == `VIDEO_SYNC) ^ (~`VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE);
            vsync   <= (state_v == `VIDEO_SYNC) ^ (~`VIDEO_V_SYNC_ACTIVE);
            visible <= (state_h == `VIDEO_ACTIVE) && (state_v == `VIDEO_ACTIVE);
            x       <= count_h - 1;
            y       <= count_v - 1;
         end
    end

    // Horizontal state machine
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            count_h <= 16'b1;
            state_h <= `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH;
        end else begin
            inc_v <= 0;
            count_h <= count_h + 16'd1;

            case (state_h)
                `VIDEO_SYNC: begin
                    if (count_h == `VIDEO_H_SYNC_PIXELS) begin
                        state_h <= `VIDEO_BACKPORCH;
                        count_h <= 16'b1;
                    end
                end
                `VIDEO_BACKPORCH: begin
                    if (count_h == `VIDEO_H_BP_PIXELS) begin
                        state_h <= `VIDEO_ACTIVE;
                        count_h <= 16'b1;
                    end
                end
                `VIDEO_ACTIVE: begin
                    if (count_h == `VIDEO_H_ACTIVE_PIXELS) begin
                        state_h <= `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH;
                        count_h <= 16'b1;
                    end
                end
                `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH: begin
                    if (count_h == `VIDEO_H_FP_PIXELS) begin
                        state_h <= `VIDEO_SYNC;
                        count_h <= 16'b1;
                        inc_v <= 1;
                    end
                end
            endcase
        end
    end

    // Vertical state machine
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            count_v <= 16'b1;
            state_v <= `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH;
        end else begin
            if (inc_v) begin
                count_v <= count_v + 16'd1;
                case (state_v)
                    `VIDEO_SYNC: begin
                        if (count_v == `VIDEO_V_SYNC_LINES) begin
                            state_v <= `VIDEO_BACKPORCH;
                            count_v <= 16'b1;
                        end
                    end
                    `VIDEO_BACKPORCH: begin
                        if (count_v == `VIDEO_V_BP_LINES) begin
                            state_v <= `VIDEO_ACTIVE;
                            count_v <= 16'b1;
                        end
                    end
                    `VIDEO_ACTIVE: begin
                        if (count_v == `VIDEO_V_ACTIVE_LINES) begin
                            state_v <= `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH;
                            count_v <= 16'b1;
                        end
                    end
                    `VIDEO_FRONTPORCH: begin
                        if (count_v == `VIDEO_V_FP_LINES) begin
                            state_v <= `VIDEO_SYNC;
                            count_v <= 16'b1;
                        end
                    end
                endcase
            end
        end
    end

endmodule
```

When attempting to synthesize this using the IceStorm toolchain, `yosys` warns that there are multiple drivers for `hsync`:

```
Warning: multiple conflicting drivers for top.\timing.hsync:
    port Q[0] of cell $techmap\timing.$procdff$109 ($adff)
    port Q[0] of cell $techmap\timing.$procdff$110 ($adff)
```

`nextpnr-ice40` then subsequently fails on the same problem:

```
ERROR: multiple drivers on net 'P1B4' ($auto$simplemap.cc:496:simplemap_adff$375.Q and $auto$simplemap.cc:496:simplemap_adff$376.Q)
ERROR: Loading design failed.
```

I've tried a few different permutations to try to resolve this, and made some observations:

- If I change the assignment in the `case (reset)` `0:` block (in the first always) to just `hsync <= 'VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE` then the result is synthesizable, and does indeed assert `hsync` constantly when not in reset as I'd expect after making that change.
- If I remove the `hsync <= (state_h == 'VIDEO_SYNC) ^ (~'VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE)` line entirely but retain the `hsync <= ~'VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE` during reset then the result is also sythesizable, and `hsync` is constantly unasserted.

(I replaced backticks with `'` above just because backtick is the Markdown metacharacter for inline verbatim text. I'm using backticks for the constants in my actual program.)

This has led me to conclude that the expression on the right hand side of `hsync <=` that is the problem. But I'm then confused as to why the very similar following `vsync <=` line doesn't produce a similar error:

```
hsync <= (state_h == `VIDEO_SYNC) ^ (~`VIDEO_H_SYNC_ACTIVE);
vsync <= (state_v == `VIDEO_SYNC) ^ (~`VIDEO_V_SYNC_ACTIVE);
```

The module behaves as I expected under simulation with `iverilog`.

I'm using Yosys 0.8 and nextpnr built from git sha1 a6a4349. I also tried upgrading to Yosys 0.9 and got the same result, but I suspect the fault is mine, not in the toolchain.

Comment: I suggest you replace your `case (reset)` with `if (reset)`. I have never seen a reset used with a case in that way. I suspect the synthesis tool also gets confused.

Comment: Thanks, @Oldfart. I had tried a few different things and so forgot to mention that I also tried both an `if` and a `case` there; I originally wrote `if` but saw some commentary elsewhere suggesting that some synthesis tools only understand `case` there. Unfortunately, this particular toolchain doesn't seem to produce a different result either way. I've updated the question to include the modified version with the `if` statements instead, with the same result.

Comment: I just ran your latest code through Vivado 2018.2 and get no errors. I start to suspect your tool is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Oldfart! That's good to know. Perhaps I've found an edge case or bug in `yosys`; I'll see if I can reproduce your success with the official Lattice tools (since I'm targeting a Lattice part) and if so, see about reporting this upstream.

Comment: Many tools are very tolerant about what they allow for asynchronous resets. But `if` is the only way that is guaranteed to work according to the synthesis standard.

Comment: Compiled with no error or warnings on `Yosys 0.7+515 (git sha1 3545c0f, clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 -fPIC -Os)` and in iCECube2 release 2017.08.27940. Both run in Ubuntu 16.04. Just my 2 cents..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern of asynchronous resets is not permitted by the IEEE synthesis standard (1364.1). Only an `if` statement can be used thus:

[image: IEEE 1364.1 - 5.2.2.1 Edge-sensitive storage device modeling with asynchronous set-reset]

Comment: Thank you. I have not yet seen that part of the standard.

Comment: Thank you! I saw some conflicting examples of this so it's good to see it straight from the standard. On reflection I realized that a synchronous reset should be fine for my purposes here anyway, so I reduced the sensitivity to just `posedge clk` with it resetting at the next clock cycle. Unfortunately that simplification (along with switching back to using `if` statement instead of `case` for testing `reset`) didn't seem to change the outcome. Did I misunderstand what part of my module you were referring to? (I've updated my question with the latest updates.)

Comment: I don't have Yosys 0.8 or 0.9 built and available; but I can't seem to see any kind of multiple driver issue with the updated code and the latest (git master) toolchain - and the code posted does now look correct.

Comment: Thanks again! I will try a build of yosys from `master` when I'm back at my computer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here were important stepping-stones:

- My reset implementation was originally asynchronous and written in a way that wasn't conforming to the Verilog synthesis standard.
- My conditional reset logic was written using `switch` rather than `if` (due to some confusing advice I saw elsewhere).

Unfortunately, the trail went dry there because after that this `timing.v` was synthesizing just fine. It turned out that the problem was actually in `top.v` instead:

```
    video_timing timing(
        .reset(reset_loc),
        .clk(vga_ck),
        .hsync(vga_hs),
        .vsync(vga_hs),
        .visible(vga_de)
    );
```

I accidentally assigned `vga_hs` to both `hsync` *and* `vsync`. ‍♂️

After changing the `vsync` line to refer to `vga_vs` instead, the design now synthesizes and behaves as expected.

Lesson learned: the problem isn't always where the compiler thinks it is!